# Convert Curl Request Over to Node.JS Server -- Attach data to the request?

Tags: node.js, curl, https

I'm learning how to process credit card payments.. Here is the test CURL...

```
 curl -k -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" -d "@json_file.txt" -o output.txt https://w1.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale
```

Where json_file.txt contains

```
{
    "InvoiceNo":"1",
    "RefNo":"1",
    "Memo":"TEST_TEST_PHONY",
    "Purchase":"1.00",
    "AccountSource":"Swiped",
    "AcctNo":"5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1",
    "ExpDate":"0816",
    "OperatorID":"xxxxxxxxxx",
}
```

I converted over to node module HTTPS

```
var https = require("https");

var options = {
    host: 'w1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net',
    port: 443,
    path: '/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale',
    headers: { "Content-Type" :"application/json", 
    "Authorization" : "Basic Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="} ,
    data: {
    "InvoiceNo":"1",
    "RefNo":"1",
    "Memo":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Purchase":"1.00",
    "AccountSource":"Swiped",
    "AcctNo":"5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1",
    "ExpDate":"0816",
    "OperatorID":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
  method: 'POST'  
};

// oops...  400 Bad Request
// The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. 

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk.toString() );
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Problem is on the original curl request, the data contained within the JSON text file is submitted as a POST attachment.  Curl request works fine.  On the other hand its not clear to me on how to do that from a node.js server.    The response headers come back fine, but I get a 400 response (malformed syntax). Anybody know how to attach JSON data as a post attachment to a HTTPS request?

Comment: Why the down vote? And why the down vote with no comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.  I totally didn't understand how the req.write() stuff works..  This code is successful.  Thanks to Dan Ourada @ Mercury Payments for his assistance. Note, all code here is pure sandbox.  No real $$ going buy buy.

```
var https = require("https");

var options = {
  host: 'w1.mercurycert.net',
  port: '443',
  path: '/PaymentsAPI/Credit/Sale',
  headers: { "Content-Type" :"application/json", "Authorization" : "Basic MDAzNTAzOTAyOTEzMTA1Onh5eg=="},
  method: 'POST'  
};

var inputdata = JSON.stringify( {
    "InvoiceNo":"1",
    "RefNo":"1",
    "Memo":"XXXXX",
    "Purchase":"1.00",
    "AccountSource":"Swiped",
    "AcctNo":"5499990123456781",
    "ExpDate":"0816",
    "OperatorID":"money2020",
  } );

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('Return info: ' + chunk);   // output the return raw data
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// attach input data to request body
req.write(inputdata);
req.end();
```

Info offered here in case anybody else gets stuck converting from a CURL command over to a Node.js http request...

And hey, after playing around with this, I'm amazed on how truly easy it is to incorporate a real (and secure) payments system into any merchant website.  (Obviously Https site required.)

Comment: For an alternative, check out the `request` library, per answer from Jed Watson, ref [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)