# Get response data with javascript

Tags: javascript, curl

using cURL store response data in $response_data i want to do same thing using javascript ?

```
$URL = "https://drive.google.com/get_video_info?docid=".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response_data = urldecode(urldecode(curl_exec($curl)));
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515976/3991696

Comment: @KhatamNaayak plain old AJAX isn't going to work for Google Drive

Comment: API only highest resolution, JS CORS issue, PHP cookie issue