# How to scrape tables from some URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

In Python it is very simple: pandas.read_html("some URL");

I am wondering what's the best way to do this in Javascript. Is there some existing library that can help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform curl request in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515936/perform-curl-request-in-javascript)

Comment: @caramba Not entirely sure. I guess I am looking for something simpler: scrapes all tables in a link and returns a list of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) this will create a [document object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) where you can perform any kind of manipulation as any normal html page.

example:

```
var doc = DOMParser.parseFromString("<html code here>", "text/html");
var tables = doc.querySelectorAll('table'); // returns NodeList
```

You should fetch the html string from another part of your program.