# Perform curl requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, curl, request

Can anyone help me how to do this in javascript if it's possible?

```
curl \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Client-ID: <client_id>' \
-d'{"channel_id":<channel_id>}' \
-X POST 'https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/channels/id'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.  For this problem, you probably want to investigate the [fetch call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515936/perform-curl-request-in-javascript/25515976

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `child_process` or convert to a fetch(or equivalent)

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('curl ...', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle result
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you want to use JS.

You can use JQUERY Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST/GET",
    async: true,
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {
       //code
    },
    error: function (xhr, exception) {
        //console.log err
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is JS Fetch API:

```
fetch("https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/channels/id", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Client-Id": "<client_id>"
  },
 method: "POST"
})
```