# Is there anyway to check if elasticsearch cluster exists or not?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on an elasticsearch (es) cluster monitoring dashboard where I want to onboard all my es clusters. I am developing the dashboard from scratch. So, I wanted to add a button on the dashboard by clicking on that user will be able to enter the name of the es cluster address/IP(first time onboarding the cluster) then hit the submit button. If that es cluster exists then user should be able to monitor the cluster, if not then, it should show some error message to the user(on the dashboard) saying that "Sorry you have entered a wrong cluster address/IP". So, how can I determine if an es cluster exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

A simple curl call to the ES cluster address and port should be enough to verify if an ES cluster exists or not.

For e.g. if we want to verify whether an ES cluster exists at http://localhost:9200, we would fire a curl call as follows:-

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/"
```

If the ES cluster exists/ has permissions to access, it would return a JSON as follows:

```
{
  "name" : "es01",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch7",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xu49eNE6SuC1Z857kG2Q5g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.16.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "4e6e4eab2297e949ec994e688dad46290d018022",
    "build_date" : "2022-01-06T23:43:02.825887787Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Else, it would return an error as follows:-

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

*Please note, that you would need to use appropriate curl syntax according to the programming language. For the example, I have considered a bash script.*

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the error message "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused" in the browser console (developer tools)? If possible how can I do it? Currently I am using javascript fetch method to display the es API data.

Comment: Please refer to [CURL Request in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515936/perform-curl-request-in-javascript) to check how the curl call works in javascript.